# Apply conditional formatting on few columns based on data in one column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I was trying to apply conditional formatting to few cells on multiple column based on data of one column but do not get expected result.

[image]

When `Name` has data then I want to fill border of all column (SL, Name, Conveyance) like **Expected Formatting**. If `Name` column is blank then there should no border in corresponding row.

[image]

[image]

I have tried below formulas in different ways but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
=IF(C6:C11<>"",TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(C6<>"",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: `=$C6<>""` should work

Comment: I am wondering that, I already tried it but do not get expected result that time. It is working now very well.

Answer (score 1):

To make the lines enter this in conditional formatting:

```
=NOT($C6="") or $C6<>""
```

[image]

And to remove the lines, enter this (notice I remove the side line) to this:

```
=$C6=""
```

[image]

So my final "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager" looks like this:

[image]

And the **final result**:

[image]

Comment: Problem was solved by `Tim William` with comment `=$C6<>""` Thanks for your answer.